# Why do NumPy operations with complex infinities lead to funny results?

Tags: python, numpy

I've noticed funny results with complex infinities.

```python
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.isinf(1j * np.inf)
Out[2]: True

In [3]: np.isinf(1 * 1j * np.inf)
Out[3]: True

In [4]: np.isinf(1j * np.inf * 1)
Out[4]: False
```

This is `nan` related. But the end result is bizarre.

Is it a numpy bug? Anything I should do differently?

Comment: `numpy.inf` is a regular float, not a NumPy object. Python's built-in complex types just don't have careful inf/nan handling.

Comment: Come to think of it, I'm not sure how much sense componentwise inf/nan makes for complex number calculations. You can't really tell what `arg(inf+inf*j)` is supposed to be, or what the signs of the result should be if you try to multiply it by `1+1j`. It seems reasonable that multiplying complex infinities with anything would rapidly produce NaNs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a NumPy bug. `numpy.inf` is a regular Python float, and the strange results come from the regular Python complex multiplication algorithm, which is [this](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/complexobject.c#l42):

```
Py_complex
_Py_c_prod(Py_complex a, Py_complex b)
{
    Py_complex r;
    r.real = a.real*b.real - a.imag*b.imag;
    r.imag = a.real*b.imag + a.imag*b.real;
    return r;
}
```

When the inputs have infinite real or imaginary parts, complex multiplication tends to cause `inf-inf` subtraction and `0*inf` multiplication, leading to `nan` components in the result. We can see that `1j * numpy.inf` has one `nan` component and one `inf` component:

```
In [5]: 1j * numpy.inf
Out[5]: (nan+infj)
```

and multiplying the result by `1` produces two `nan` components:

```
In [4]: 1j * numpy.inf * 1
Out[4]: (nan+nanj)
```